# Java concurrent programming - endless loop

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I am reading the book *Introducing Play Framework: Java Web Application Development* (ISBN 978-1-4842-5645-9) and there is this example on `Callable`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CallableClient {
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    // Step1 : Create a Runnable
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callable callableTask = new CallableTask();
        // Step 2: Configure Executor
        // Uses FixedThreadPool executor
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(callableTask);
        boolean listen = true;
        while (listen) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                String result;
                try {
                    result = future.get();
                    listen = false;
                    System.out.println(result);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**My question is, if the computation of the `Future` throws and exception, will the `while` loop run forever?**

---

In my opinion, yes, it will loop forever.

First, if the `Future` computation throws an exception, then

- `future.isDone()`

always evaluates to `true`. So we reach the inside of the `if`, where the stopping condition can be set. Still Ok.

Second, as per future [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), when reaching line

- `result = future.get();`

it will always throw `ExecutionException` because the computation threw an exception. This exception is caught in the `try-catch` block, without reaching the stopping condition precondition, which is

- `listen = false`

Lastly, the above will create an endless cycle.

Is there any mistake in my assumptions or is the author of the example really wrong?

Comment: Add listen = false; line on the catch block. This will stop the execution if any exception occurs

Comment: @SivaRahul A break statement would be more appropiate.

Comment: "*In my opinion, yes, it will loop forever.*" Why do you even need to deduce the behaviour if you're not 100% sure? You have a 95% of a working minimal example here. Just make `CallableTask` throw a RuntimeException as the only statement in its `call` method, run it, and observe the result. I did it, and it took less time than I imagine it took for you to type this question.

Comment: @Talos And adding to the [Comment by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72460628/java-concurrent-programming-endless-loop#comment128006334_72460628), after you try it yourself and come to a conclusion, come back here to draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program mentioned above **cycles forever**, if the callable throws an exception.

---

This is a code snippet with the callable that throws an exceptions. Executing compiled snippet loops forever.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class CallableClient {

    public static class CallableTask implements Callable<String> {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callable<String> callableTask = new CallableTask();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(callableTask);
        boolean listen = true;
        while (listen) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                String result;
                try {
                    result = future.get();
                    listen = false;
                    System.out.println(result);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```